# How to send input string to NCR Aloha POS?

Tags: input, response, keyboard-events, keystroke

So, I'm trying to send an input to POS through C# Console Application. I need to be able to read the input and respond.

I tried this code from the internet. But haven't had any luck. The SendString function is the one sending the input!

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendString("~99999^");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesizes keystrokes corresponding to the specified Unicode string,
        /// sending them to the currently active window.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="~Hello^">The string to send.</param>
        public static void SendString(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Send String Function....");
            Console.WriteLine($"String : {s}");
            // Construct list of inputs in order to send them through a single SendInput call at the end.
            List<INPUT> inputs = new List<INPUT>();

            // Loop through each Unicode character in the string.
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                // First send a key down, then a key up.
                foreach (bool keyUp in new bool[] { false, true })
                {
                    // INPUT is a multi-purpose structure which can be used 
                    // for synthesizing keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.
                    INPUT input = new INPUT
                    {
                        // Need a keyboard event.
                        type = INPUT_KEYBOARD,
                        u = new InputUnion
                        {
                            // KEYBDINPUT will contain all the information for a single keyboard event
                            // (more precisely, for a single key-down or key-up).
                            ki = new KEYBDINPUT
                            {
                                // Virtual-key code must be 0 since we are sending Unicode characters.
                                wVk = 0,

                                // The Unicode character to be sent.
                                wScan = c,

                                // Indicate that we are sending a Unicode character.
                                // Also indicate key-up on the second iteration.
                                dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE | (keyUp ? KEYEVENTF_KEYUP : 0),

                                dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo(),
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    // Add to the list (to be sent later).
                    inputs.Add(input);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("About to Send String now!!! Press anything.");
            //Console.ReadLine();
            // Send all inputs together using a Windows API call.
            SendInput((uint)inputs.Count, inputs.ToArray(), Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
            Console.WriteLine("String Sent!!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
        const int INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
        const int INPUT_HARDWARE = 2;
        const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
        const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
        const uint KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004;
        const uint KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008;
        const uint XBUTTON1 = 0x0001;
        const uint XBUTTON2 = 0x0002;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

        struct INPUT
        {
            public int type;
            public InputUnion u;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct InputUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public MOUSEINPUT mi;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public KEYBDINPUT ki;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            /*Virtual Key code.  Must be from 1-254.  If the dwFlags member specifies KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, wVk must be 0.*/
            public ushort wVk;
            /*A hardware scan code for the key. If dwFlags specifies KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, wScan specifies a Unicode character which is to be sent to the foreground application.*/
            public ushort wScan;
            /*Specifies various aspects of a keystroke.  See the KEYEVENTF_ constants for more information.*/
            public uint dwFlags;
            /*The time stamp for the event, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the system will provide its own time stamp.*/
            public uint time;
            /*An additional value associated with the keystroke. Use the GetMessageExtraInfo function to obtain this information.*/
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            public uint uMsg;
            public ushort wParamL;
            public ushort wParamH;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

    }
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, would be much appreciated. Thanks.